# Rails rendering of controller_action.js.erb (AJAX) with the respond_to - can't it be done with coffe/haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript, haml

I am one of those people who use HAML instead of ERB, and Coffeescript "instead" of Javascript. My application uses a lot of AJAX responding, e.g.:

```
def controller_action

  # Lots of code here...

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {
    }
    format.js
  end
end
```

Which them renders controller_action.js.erb that could look like this:

```
var some_partial;
some_partial = $("#some_partial");
some_partial.children().remove();
$('#some_partial').append('<%= j render("some_partial") %>');
```

As I have straight to HAML and Coffeescript, and therefore can't understand the ERB and Javascript syntax (I know there are cool sites like js2coffee.org and html2haml.heroku.com, but I'd rather that my application uses code languages I understand).

This brings me to my question: Is it really not possible to have a controller_action.js.coffee.html.haml or something like that?

Comment: Which version of rails are you using?

Comment: Hi @ValentinVasilyev , I use Rails 3.2.8.

Comment: It should be either .js.coffee or .html.haml, but **never** .js.coffee.html.haml.

Comment: I know :-) The question is not what name my haml/coffeescript file should have, but more if it is possible to combine haml and coffeescript, like you can combine erb and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

By default rails 3.2.13 supports these content formats:

```
irb(main):003:0> Mime::SET.map(&:to_sym)
=> [:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip]
```

Other formats need to be added manually, for example in config/initializers/mime_types.rb:

```
Mime::Type.register "text/markdown", :markdown
```